# Child element doesn't except property value

Tags: qml

I have a property defined inside QML i.e. `txt_margin` and `txt_size` to be passed on to child element (i.e. Text) but the child item doesn't update with this new value.

Here is portion of my code

```
    Row {
       . . .

        readonly property int txt_margin: 4
        readonly property int txt_size: 15
       . . .

        Rectangle {
           . . .
           . . .
           . . .

            Text {
                . . .
                . . .
                font.pixelSize: txt_size   // This doesn't work
                anchors.leftMargin: txt_margin // This doesn't work
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is `Row` the top-level declaration in the QML file? If not, that's the problem, use `id: row1` and `row1.txt_size`

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't using fully qualified name.

Comment: If the property is on the top-level item, you don't need to. But go a level deeper and you will have to use the full qualified name indeed